# A simple Blackberry application that opens a URL

Tags: blackberry

I've been asked to look into developing a very simple Blackberry application, that when opened basically opens a URL in the native browser.

I see there are two ways of developing Blackberry apps; Java and Web (Javascript). The example code I have found to open a URL is this:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(URL);
```

This is the Java version. Is there a Javascript version? Can I make a Blackberry app with just Javascript?

**What would be the simplest way of developing/publishing this type of application?** I don't want to go over the top unless I need to with installing the Eclipse IDE etc.

Also, I develop on a Mac, but do have access to a Windows machine if required.

Comment: Your easiest way would be an URL app: Here is the article: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-Create-a-URL-launching-application-for-BlackBerry/ta-p/1164027

Answer (score 0):

There's Webworks, which is their framework to write apps in Javascript:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/webworks/api/index.html

It's essentially a glorified Java app with a BrowserField widget and some scaffolding to allow the Javascript to call into Java code. You might be able to do something like this to change your location:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

I'm not sure that Webworks is easier overall than writing Java code, but there is the option at least

Comment: That would be a waste of space to pile up huge WebWorks app just to do location.href = "xxx"